# when going to admin giving error site url does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

When i am trying to go admin path in the it is giving me error that saying that site matching query does not exist this never happens to me before

[image]

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include('core.urls', namespace='core'))
]
```

here is my main project url

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    ItemDetailView,
    CheckoutView,
    HomeView,
    OrderSummaryView,
    add_to_cart,
    remove_from_cart,
    remove_single_item_from_cart,
    PaymentView,
    AddCouponView,
    RequestRefundView
)

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('checkout/', CheckoutView.as_view(), name='checkout'),
    path('order-summary/', OrderSummaryView.as_view(), name='order-summary'),
    path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
    path('add-to-cart/<slug>/', add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart'),
    path('add-coupon/', AddCouponView.as_view(), name='add-coupon'),
    path('remove-from-cart/<slug>/', remove_from_cart, name='remove-from-cart'),
    path('remove-item-from-cart/<slug>/', remove_single_item_from_cart,
         name='remove-single-item-from-cart'),
    path('payment/<payment_option>/', PaymentView.as_view(), name='payment'),
    path('request-refund/', RequestRefundView.as_view(), name='request-refund')
]
```

my app urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely something to do with your `urls`. Please double check you have included the admin route in the urls and make sure there are no path conflicts. For more help, you should paste your code of urls or settings where you think the error might be.

This is the admin path for reference:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [path("admin/", admin.site.urls)]
```

Comment: I have edited the question with urls

Comment: Try adding `django.contrib.sites` in django `INSTALLED_APPS` and also add `SITE_ID=1` in your django setting file.

Comment: adding site_is=1 works but can you explain why this happen improve the answer and i will accept this thank you man

Comment: SITE_ID means in the database table you create a object where you will add site name according to your app like apple.com.
Here is the reference if you need more information, hope this helps!(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework)